# Modules can be viewed as monoid objects in some appropriate monoidal category?

Tags: modules, monoidal-categories, graded-modules

I need to find a solution to have an inverse structure form: not classic modules over a monoid but *monoids over modules*.
I had received this answer from [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-modules-over-a-monoid-exist-but-is-not-possible-to-have-a-monoids-over-modules-What-prevents-this-inverse-structure)

> monoid objects are the minimal structure for modules to make sense over, and modules themselves don't have enough structure to be monoid objects in general.

But is possible to use *sheafification* or *stackification* to 'feed' modules to give them the 'missing structure' to do a module an monoidal identity ? Is there an inverse way to overcome this structure missing problem for modules ?

Then it says

> the categorification process can be made to continue by finding a monoid object in the category of modules, and then passing to modules over this

If solution is that, how is possible to give the missing structure for a single module using the *category of modules* ?

> in the set-enriched case, a module over a monoid is just a set equipped with a (left) action by that monoid. You can't multiply elements in this thing together; you can only let them be “scaled” by elements in the base monoid.

Eh... this is problem: "scaled by elements": I don't want this. If I use a sheaf structure, augmented R-algebra or stackification can I have a monoid over a module ?

Comment: In the category of $R$-modules, the monoid objects are just the $R$-algebras. An $R$-algebra $A$ has an underlying $R$-module structure, and we can form $A$-modules.

Comment: 'Module' is basically a synonim for monoid (ring) *action*. When you have a module, it already presumes a monoid (object in a monoidal category) and a monoid action.

Comment: yes..but if module is a *monoid (ring) action* I wish to *add* (I try to understand what is this 'add') *extra* structure because I want a *field* structure for my module. I know that *finite (integral) domain* or *finite division ring* is (or returns as) a field so I don't find only a monoid *action* , but an action structure within for my module (a *field structured* module), maybe a monad structure, not only an external monoid *action*. R-modules stand for ring, but I need to have a field because I know that every field is a ring but also `Every finite division ring is a field`